Fitnesse DbFit SQL Server connection
I'm not able to connect to SQL Server using Fitnesse DbFit, I have this configuration:
!|dbfit.SqlServerTest|
!|Connect|${DRIVER}|${USER}|${USERNAME}|${Password}|

I get an error the user property exceeded the maximum number of 128 character while trying to connect to SQL Server using DBFiT Fitnesse.
I have all required jar in my lib dir.
I want to connect to SQL Server using Fitnesse DbFit

Your string doesn't correspond to their docs? https://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/docs/database-specific-information.html
